# T-SQL select and update with calculations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble seeing how to do this but here is my problem.

I need to select a field, do calculations on it and update that field based on those calculations all in one fail swoop. I'm just not seeing how to do it. Is this sort of thing even possible in T-SQL or is it temp table time?

Thanks.

Comment: Pls post some sample input & output

Comment: Do we always have a spike of these questions in September?

Comment: How about doing your own research? Posting on SO shouldn't be the first thing that comes to mind... Anyways, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `UPDATE dbo.Table SET Field1 = Field1 + 1` will update the field based on a calculation.  Without more specifics, we can't answer.

Comment: The field selected needs to be divided by a number, the result of that then needs to be muliplied by a different number and then updated. There is no code to show this, thats what Im trying to figure out. I'd rather do it in a single statement if its possible.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's also helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need normal calculation you can do with the update

```
 update my_table  
 set my_column = (my_colum *3)/another_column 
 where col2 = 'value_to_find';
```